# How to solve dfTeX error: pdflatex (file myfigure.png): reading image file failed

Tags: graphics, overleaf, compilation-error

I'm working with Overleaf on my Master Thesis and I'm now blocked for this technical problem.

I already insert many images of type (.pdf, .eps, .png, .jpeg...) and always the figure is inserted correctly.

Now, without apparent reasons, I can't insert more images. I try to eliminate and upload again the image, I try to change format, I try to use another image, but it always shows this error:

[image: the error Overleaf shows]

If I use a figure I already uploaded, it works.
Where can be the problem?
May be a question of space? But the image is correctly uploaded and the editor find it, but it can't read it. Why?

Thank in advance for an answer.

Comment: When the LaTeX-compiler is compiling a .tex-file, a file with extension .log is produced which contains info-messages/warning-messages/error-messages etc delivered by the LaTeX-compiler. Overleaf is just an environment/online-platform for maintaining .tex-files and editing them and running the LaTeX-compiler for compiling them. Overleaf's messages are just incomplete snippets/excerpts of the .log-file (which is called raw-log in Overleaf-jargon) produced by the LaTeX-compiler. E.g., it should be "pdfTeX error", not "dfTeX error". ...

Comment: ... not "dfTeX error". If you wish detailed info on what exactly went wrong during compilation you need to view what is called "raw-log" in Overleaf. Probably you can via copy-paste append the content of the raw-log to your question.

Comment: the sintaxis is correct, i copied from another figure that works:
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{1_introduction/1.3_models/curve}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

Comment: from the raw-log file i found the complete error: 

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./1_introduction/1.3_models/curve.png): reading image file failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: I think the image itself is corrupted in some sense. I think is not a problem of editing but of the image. I take it from a paper by my advisor, is possible that is encripted?

Comment: @FrancescoCavalleri  As this kind of message is produced by the routines for reading image-files in specific file formats I guess that the file `./1_introduction/1.3_models/curve.png` is considered corrupt/not a valid .png-file by the latex-compiler in use.

Comment: @FrancescoCavalleri Sorry, as I don't have the image available for examination I cannot tell whether there is something wrong with it. Can you open the image file with a program for viewing/manipulating images, e.g., GIMP?  (Seems the image is found, otherwise you would not get a "reading image file failed"-error but a "file not found" error.)

Comment: copy the file locally and load the png into any image editor gimp, microsoft paint whatever/ can it be viewed? if so re-save it and re-upload with hopefully a less corrupt png format

Comment: I solve the problem! I download again the paper and i extract from here images, It works now